# The problem of constancy:How to find the range of logarithmic base a for the problem of logarithmic inequality?

Tags: equation-solving

```
Sqrt[x] < Log[a, x], 0 < x <= 1/4
```

The inequality on the left side remains valid within the range of x on the right side. How can I find the range of logarithmic base a?

```
In[24]:= Reduce[{Sqrt[x] < Log[a, x], 0 < x <= 1/4}, a]

Out[24]= 
Log[x]/Sqrt[x] \[Element] Reals && 0 < x <= 1/4 && 
 x^(1/Sqrt[x]) < a < 1
```

The scope of a was not solved using the above code

Comment: `Reduce[Sqrt[Interval[{0, 1/4}]] < Log[a, Interval[{0, 1/4}]], a]` returns the correct result a>1/16 together with a superfluous `Interval[{0, 1/2}] == 0`, that I do not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done as follows.

```
ForAll[x, 0 < x <= 1/4, Sqrt[x] < Log[a, x]];
Resolve[%, Reals]
```

> `-4 Log[2] < Log[a] < 0`

```
Reduce[%,a,Reals]
```

> `1/16 < a < 1`

Comment: With v13.3 on a Mac, this `Resolve` appears to run indefinitely. How quickly did you get a result?

Comment: @BobHanlon:`{1.625, -4 Log[2] < Log[a] < 0}` in 13.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: In 13.1 on Windows 10 running without any response for more than dozen minutes

Comment: (-1 ) Does not work in 11.3 and 13.2 on windows 11.